# Video.js HTML/CSS Fluid Contain within Container

Tags: html, css, video.js

I have a standard Video.js player with the fluid property set to true like the following.

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.9.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="video">
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js" data-setup='{"fluid": true}' controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
  </video>
</div>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/6.9.0/video.js"></script>
```

I also have the following CSS.

```
.video {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Now technically in the actual site those width and height properties are more dynamic. Depending on page size and all that. So it's not like I'll know what the width and height will be.

Currently what happens in both the example I made to reproduce it, and my site is that the fluid only maps to the width, and doesn't take into account the height of the container.

What I'm looking to do is make the video fluid (no black bars around video) and contain it within the width and height of the parent div. If the video needs to be smaller than the container div in terms of width (due to fluidness) it should center within the div.

I have posted a CodePen below as an example of the code above.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvxbJB

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to set your container div to a relative position, center that div, and then set padding to get the aspect ratio you want (if any).  Then absolutely position your video tag with a height and width of 100%.

```
.video {
  position: relative;
  /* padding-bottom: 56.25%; uncomment to get an aspect ratio of 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#my-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Hope that helps!